# How can I specify the latest time of day with DateTime

Tags: .net, datetime

I am using a `System.DateTime` object to allow a user to select a date range. The user is only able to select a date (not time) using a third party calendar so I will need to automatically specify the time of day it should use (ie: 00:00:00 or 23:59:59) after the date is chosen.

How can I specify the time after the date is already stored as a DateTime object by the calendar selector? I could use the `AddHours, AddMinutes, AddSeconds` methods but those are relative to the current time which may not be 00:00:00.

The `startDate` will need to have a time of 00:00:00 and `endDate` have a time of 23:59:59 to account for the entire days.

Comment: Latest time of day being 23:59:59.999 ?

Comment: What do you mean by "latest time of day"?

Comment: As precise as it will handle (but really, seconds should be plenty fine)

Comment: @d03boy: What do you mean "change the time"? Do you mean set the PC clock to that time?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

To get the last instant for today:

```
DateTime d = new DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day);
d = d.AddDays(1);
d = d.AddTicks(-1);
```

---

In response to your edit, here's what I would do:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day);
DateTime end = start.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);

// Or - just use end = start.AddDays(1), and use a < for comparison
```

Comment: +1. I was thinking the same exact thing. Do you all have some sort of special keyboard with SO-intellisense/auto-complete built in?

Comment: AddDays(1) will set it to 00:00:00 on the next day then?

Comment: @d03boy: exactly. AddDays() will be exactly 24 hours later. In this case, at 00:00:00.0. If you want the very instant before that, subtract one tick.

Comment: This is assuming time is already set to 00:00:00 which may not be a safe assumption here. Can you directly set the time somehow?

Comment: @d03boy
Jon B instanciated a DateTime by specifying the year, month and day. That sets the time to 0 so there is not need to do add .Date before adding a day in this case.

Comment: @d03boy: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x.aspx : "The time of day for the resulting DateTime is midnight (00:00:00). The Kind property is initialized to DateTimeKind..::.Unspecified."

Comment: @d03boy: When you create a new DateTime and don't specify the time, it is 00:00:00. If you want to specify it anyway, just use new DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: Value is set to latest possible moment of a day. Sharp and precise solution. +1

Comment: AddDay(1).AddTickes(-1) in Database, it will show the next date when using SQL query in this case it may make a confusion. However, when get it into CLI the date is represent correctly.

Answer (score 133):

If you already have a `DateTime` object created and want to replace the time with the 11:59:59PM for that given date, then you can use the `.Date` property to get the date with time set to 00:00:00 and then add the hours, minutes and seconds. For example:

```
var dt = yourDateInstance.Date.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59);
```

If by latest time, you mean 11:59:59 PM, then this should also work:

```
var dt = new DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day, 23, 59, 59);
```

Comment: Indeed. There's nothing that says that you have to use Now.XXX to generate a year, month, day, hour, minute, or second. You can make a DateTime that represents any given instance of time.

Comment: What if I'm not entirely sure if its already set to 00:00:00? Can I directly set it to a time instead of it being relative?

Comment: Yes, the property .Date returns the date component with time set to 00:00:00. That's why the code says: youDateInstance.Date before adding the hours.

Comment: Very good! Thanks for the explanation. You may want to add that to your answer for us newbs who might not notice it.

Comment: Technically the "latest time of the day" would have the max number of ticks as well..  Making the fastest answer: DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);

Comment: I have this in my projects         public static DateTime EndOfDate(this DateTime dateTime)
        {
            return new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day, 23, 59, 59, 999);
        } makes it a lot easier. ie. DateTime.Now.EndOfDate()

Comment: Not every day has 24 hours in it, do you want to get paged on NYE? cause that's how you get paged on NYE

Comment: It's not correct. You will have records in database with timestamp 23:59:59.100
You need to take dateEnd.AddDays(1) and use it as WHERE date < dateEnd comparison, withour "equals" condition

Answer (score 28):

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
```

Answer (score 15):

Your question has already been answered, but IMHO a better way is not to bother attempting to subtract a tick, a second, or whatever from the end of the range, and compare using strictly less than.

So that if you want all dates in an **inclusive** range from startDate to endDate, ignoring the time, you could use the following in C#:

```
if ((myDate >= startDate.Date) && (myDate < endDate.Date.AddDays(1)))
{
    // ... it's in the range
}
```

or in T-SQL, assuming your @StartDate and @EndDate are exactly midnight, something like:

```
WHERE SomeDate >= @StartDate AND SomeDate < DATEADD(d,1,@EndDate)
```

**UPDATE**

Updated example to show an inclusive range in response to comments.

Comment: IMO, endDate should still be included in the search. What if I choose June 2nd and June 2nd as my starting and end dates?

Comment: Then you could just add a day to endDate and use Joe's code ;-)

Answer (score 15):

Based on the other answers I created this convenient extension method:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime EndOfDay(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return dateTime.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Using an Extension Method**

```
public static DateTime EndOfTheDay(this DateTime date)
{
    return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day).AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
}
```

The result here would provide you with the latest time possible by getting the beginning of the day - add a day and then subtract one tick.
Other methods add Hours, Minutes and Seconds however those solutions depending on code functions will cause issues for any time between 23:59:59.000000 and 23:59:59.999999

For example if I want to know if a value is before a certain end date / time , the possibility with other solutions is that they would miss values in the millisecond range.

Comment: Very clean, reusable solution.  Microsoft has great documentation on implementing extension methods [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-and-call-a-custom-extension-method).

Comment: Even simpler: return date.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);

Answer (score 7):

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today;
DateTime stopDate = startDate.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
```

As a note, `DateTime.Today` returns (from MSDN)

> A System.DateTime set to today's date,
>   with the time component set to
>   00:00:00.

So as others have noted, add a day, then subtract the smallest time quantum (a tick), and you get the last possible time for the current day.

Of course, you might have to think about TimeZones and such depending where the code runs versus where the user is.  UTC time might be good, but that might bump you off a day (either way) depending where your code runs.

Comment: Glad your thinking of timezones. That has been taken care of.

Answer (score 3):

For example

```
DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)
```

Or `AddTicks/AddMilliseconds/AddMinutes`... based on the precision you need.

Answer (score 3):

Why not  **ToDayEnd**() extension

```
/// <summary>
    /// Gets the value of the End of the day (23:59)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="target"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DateTime ToDayEnd(this DateTime target)
    {
        return target.Date.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1);
    }
```

But if you would really mean the absolute end of the day then AddTicks(-1) is the answer.

Comment: What library is that in?

Comment: Oh my bad.. it was one of the libraries I was using. I kept using it so much that I thought it was part of the Sytem.DateTime :)

Comment: Hehe. Thought that might be the case

Comment: @JoePhillips you can tell that this is an extension method, 1 it is static, 2 in the arguments passed in the keyword this.

Comment: @Ken I agree. That doesn’t tell me what library I would need to import to use it though. It could be a custom library or it could be in the .net framework

Comment: @JoePhillips I don't want to sound rude because I am not trying to be; everything there is C# .NET base  and DateTime is a rudimentary component , so I am not following why you might think you need a library to use it ?  If I can understand why maybe in the future I can formulate my answers better.

Comment: @Ken you don’t need a library to use it. It is an extension that you can write to call on your dates instead of repeating yourself.

Comment: @akd I know it is an extension - see my comments. I am not understanding why JoePhillips is asking about a library .. just for my answers in the future I would like to be clear enough so that kind of question does not arise - I don't understand why Joe is having an issue do you ? [.Net noob?] (as this seems basic extension method to me).

Comment: When I first answered this question I had written my answer as this extension already exists in System.DateTime. However that was not the case and @JoePhillips corrected me. It was just an extension in a custom library that I was using. So all my fault  This often happens when answers are corrected and comments seem to lose the connection. Hope this clears the mess for this answer.

Comment: I asked this question 11 years ago :)

Answer (score 2):

yourDateInstance.CloseDate = yourDateInstance.CloseDate.Date.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1);

Answer (score 1):

use this

DateTime YourNewDate = new DateTime(YourDate .Year, YourDate .Month, YourDate .Day, 23, 59, 59, 99);

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: This is actually the same as the second part of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

this will give you the expected result:

```
DateTime startDate= DateTime.Now.Date;
DateTime endDate= startDate.AddDays(2).Add(new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59));
//startDate: 28/9/2017 0:0:0 endDate: 29/9/2017 23:59:59
```

Comment: While your code does work , it can cause issues - namely the end of day is not 23:59:59 unless your significance is in seconds. If however it is in what the DateTime data might be stored as (milliseconds) it is best to be inclusive of milliseconds as the significant value. DateTime is stored in memory as a millisecond value in as well. [milliseconds from 1 Jan 1970].

Comment: @Ken DateTime is stocked in ticks (only in ticks, in fact).

Answer (score 1):

var startDate = UIModel.StartDate;
var endDate = UIModel.EndDate.AddDays(1);

SQL query:
... WHERE date >= @startDate AND date < @endDate

- so don't include "euqal" comparison for end date in the SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

I think is better to use an Extention method to get start time of day or end time of day everywhere.

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
    {
        public static DateTime GetEndTimeOfDateTime(this DateTime datetime)
        {
            if(datetime==null) return datetime;

            return new DateTime(datetime.Year, datetime.Month, datetime.Day, 23, 59, 59);
        }

        public static DateTime GetStartTimeOfDateTime(this DateTime datetime)
        {
            if(datetime==null) return datetime;

            return new DateTime(datetime.Year, datetime.Month, datetime.Day, 0, 0, 0);
        }
}
```