# Setting time to 23:59:59

Tags: c#, datetime, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I specify the latest time of day with DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821445/how-can-i-specify-the-latest-time-of-day-with-datetime)

I need to compare a date range and am missing rows who's date is the upper comparison date but the time is higher than midnight. Is there a way to set the upper comparison's time to 23:59:59?

Comment: Are you getting the dates from SQL or another database? (you mentioned rows). There may be a specific precision involved that you have to compensate for.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
yourDateTime.Date.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59);
```

Comment: Just hope that there's nothing with a time of 23:59:59.500.

Comment: This is data that is entered between 7:00 am and 4:00 pm. The only thing that could potentially be a problem doesn't pass a time to this database I am working with. I am sure I'll be fine.Definitely something another looking for a similar solution should be worried about.

Comment: I understand the downvoting, it's not the best or most charming solution. However, I'm glad it answered the question (as technically, it complied with the question stated ;-)).

Comment: yourDateTime.Date gives me 8 AM...

Comment: DateTime startDate= DateTime.Now.Date;
DateTime endDate= startDate.AddDays(2).Add(new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59));
// result : startDate: 28/9/2017 0:0:0 endDate: 29/9/2017 23:59:59

Answer (score 39):

Why not have the upper comparison being midnight on the day *after* the last one you're interested in, and then use that with an exclusive comparison?

```
DateTime upperExclusive = lastInclusive.Date.AddDays(1);
if (dateInclusive >= date && date < upperExclusive)
{
    ....
}
```

This feels like a cleaner solution than finding the last second of the day - aside from anything else, you'd still be missing values of 23:59:59.500 etc with your current scheme.

Obligatory plug: I'm not a huge fan of the BCL date/time API. You may want to keep tabs on [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) - a port of [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) to .NET.

Comment: You could also do lastInclusive.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1) which would give you 23:59:59.999999 :)

Comment: @AdamMarshall: You could, yes. But exclusive upper bounds are generally neater.

Comment: @AdamMarshall this should be a comment on webleeuws answer - the accepted answer because this truly works well. While the OP wants a comparison - I simply need to set it in a client when user selects an end date.

Answer (score 4):

If your doing a compare why don't you compare against less that the start of the next day?

Eg. if it was a Linq query:

```
someList.Where(x => (currentDaysDate <= x.ItemDate ) && (x.ItemDate < nextDaysDate))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use one day later than the upper comparison, and `<` on the upper side instead of `<=`.  That way, you can get times that are even later (fraction of a second) than the one you specified.

Alternatively, compare using the `DateTime.Date` property instead of the DateTime directly. This will "strip off" the time portion, so your dates in the search will automatically be treated as midnight.

Answer (score 2):

Create an EndOfDay extension method

```
 public static DateTime EndOfDay (this DateTime d)
    {
        return DateTime.Parse(d.ToShortDateString().Trim() + " 23:59:59");
    }
```

Comment: The behavior of DateTime.Parse() and ToShortDateString() depends on current system locale. Your code will fail in some non-English locales.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not worried about the time at all, you can use the `Date` Property of `DateTime`, which returns just the date part (with the time set to 00:00:0000)

```
if(MyDate.Date >= StartDate.Date && MyDate.Date <= EndDate.Date)
{
    //Code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this DateTime constructor - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130.aspx
allows you to specify the date as well as hours, minutes and seconds.